# Detect a click on, and style a stacked area in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Example chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent

I want to be able to detect clicks on the different areas (blue Asia, navy Africa, etc) so that I can do some stuff with all the series I have for Asia or Africa. Note: I want to be able to detect clicks on the filled areas, not the area/series points.

I guess I could do it with area.events.click, look up the coordinates and figure out if the coordinates are inside a particular area, but that seems like and awful lot of work to achieve a simple thing like that. Is there perhaps a  built-in way to listen to events like that?

Also, on a related note - is it possible to add hover and selected styles for the areas?

EDIT: It seems that it's possible to detect clicks on the areas by setting `plotOptions.series.trackByArea` to `true`, but it seems that this way I cannot distinguish between a click on the point vs a click on the area. Any ideas how I could reliably distinguish them?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191665/detect-a-click-on-and-add-hover-selected-style-for-x-axis-on-area-chart-in-high

Comment: @Gopinagh.R - not really, as this question is about the color-filled areas, while the other one is about axis lines. Closely related: yes, exact duplicate: nope...

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it by click on area and display name of serie

http://jsfiddle.net/c2P63/5/

```
events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                        alert(this.name);
                        alert(event.x);
                        alert(event.y);
                    }   
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick but now I am facing a new issue: I cannot distinguish between a click on the point/marker and on the area. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: this answer is not really correct, clicking on a area, gives the name of its below area, not the clicked area. and as @ragulka said, it triggers multiple click event (an event for each hovered point of series).