# Detect a click on, and add hover/selected style for x axis on area chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Example chart: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked-percent

1) Can I have a hover style and also perhaps a selected style for the x axis, much like in Highstocks (move the mouse over the chart to see a vertical line on hover): http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/area

2) Can I detect a click on this line?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I have a hover style and also perhaps a selected style for the x axis, much like in Highstock

Of course, you can. *Disable* the `Hover` for series and *enable* the `cross hairs` in the [**`plotOptions`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions).

```
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: { enabled: true   }
                        }
                  } 
            }
       }
```

**Enable Crosshairs**

```
tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true
        }
```

> Can I detect a click on this line?

For triggering an alert upon clicking the line, just add

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                 point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            alert ('Clicked on the line');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

combined answer for both of your questions, fiddled version is [**`here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/qAL6M/).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do what I want. It seems that I need to use `plotOptions.series.trackByArea: true` in order to catch clicks on the actual crosshair line, instead of just on the points (markers) though.  Do you know if I can leave Hover enabled and have different hover style when I am hovering over a single point (right now all of the points have exactly the same hover style - I'd like to keep that and when I move close enough to specific point, then I want to give that point extra highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes: see tooltip.crosshairs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.crosshairs

2) I am not sure. You can detect a click on the series, which should give you what you would need from clicking the crosshair line.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use crosshairs for that

```
tooltip:{
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true
}
```

here shared true will show the info of both the lines in the same tooltip